What is the relation between the tensor of two $R$-modules over different rings.
I'm new to tensor products and I stumbled upon the following four short, related questions during self-study (let us assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity):

Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. When is $M \otimes_R N$ isomorphic to $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$? The question body in this post says that they are isomorphic if the map $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ is surjective. So, is $M \otimes_R N$ isomorphic to $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$ whenever $R = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Let $M$ be an abelian group. When is it true that $M$ is contained in the tensor product $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M$? If $M = \mathbb{Q}$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then it is not true as the tensor is $0$.

Let $M$ and $N$ be abelian groups. Does it make sense to define $M \otimes_R N$ for any ring $R$, noting that at least one of $M$ and $N$ is NOT an $R$-module? I'm asking this because sometimes authors write $M \otimes N$ for abelian groups (without specifying over which ring they are taking the tensor), and I really want to make sure this means tensor over $\mathbb{Z}$ only.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Is is true that $R \otimes_R M$ is isomorphic to $M$? I know this is true for the particular case $R = \mathbb{Z}$.


Thank you very much in advance!

Hi and welcome to MSE! Please ask one question only at a time.

Hi @BenSteffan, I'm sorry. I thought these questions are related to each other, so I asked them together.

The answer to your 4th question is YES for the same reason that the answer is yes for the special case $R = \mathbb{Z}$. Also, I believe the answer to your 3rd question is NO. You need both modules over the same ring $R$ to talk about tensor over $R$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#).


A sufficient condition is that the map $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ is an epimorphism; this includes the case of quotients but is more general since it also includes localizations and some other stranger things. The class of rings $R$ with this property are known as solid rings, and were classified by Bousfield and Kan.

A sufficient condition is that $R$ has characteristic $0$ and $M$ is torsion-free. This follows from the fact that torsion-free abelian groups are flat, and tensoring with a flat module preserves the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow R$ given by multiples of the identity if $R$ has characteristic $0$.

No, to define a tensor product over $R$ of course both inputs must have an $R$-module structure. If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups then without any further information $A \otimes B$ refers to the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$.

It's (canonically) isomorphic to $M$.



Thank you for your patience with my questions and this nice answer.
